# Difference between creating object using prototype and object literal notation

Tags: javascript

Hello i want to know the difference between this line:

```
var MyClass={
   init:function(){

   }
}
```

and

```
var Myclass=function(){};
Myclass.prototype.init=function(){}
```

Comment: One is a class; the other isn't.

Comment: which is better to use on webpage i'm new in web development so i saw those codes and i want to know better this theme

Comment: It depends on whether you need a class or an object.

Comment: @SLaks are you sure that One is a class? or probably second one? One it's a object literal notation. Second constructor function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var MyClass={
   init:function(){

   }
}
```

defines an object called `MyClass` with a member function `init`. This is object literal notation.
There is only single instance of this object; you can't create a `new` one.
You can only say for example

```
MyClass.init();
```

you can't say

```
var foo = new MyClass(); (this will cause an error)
```

On the other hand,

```
var Myclass=function(){};
Myclass.prototype.init=function(){}
```

is different; it defines a "class" (or constructor function as it can be called) which has a function `init` but which you can create multiple instances of; each instance will have the init() function.

```
var foo = new Myclass();
var bar = new Myclass();
foo.init();
bar.init();
```

So which you use really depends on what you need it for; if you're making an object that has some utility functions or maybe represents a service which only needs a single copy ever, the first is fine; whereas if you need to be able to make multiple instances because each instance's data might need to change indepdendently, use the second.

Comment: Thanks this help me alot